# why go channel is not garbage collected and closed even after completion of function

Tags: go, channel

```
    package main

import (
        "fmt"

    )

    func main(){
        leak()
        for{}
      }

func leak() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("i am stuck here")
        val := <-ch
        fmt.Println("We received a value:", val)
        
    }()
    fmt.Println("i have finished my fuction")
}
```

here since my channel "ch" is defined inside leak() function, so my understanding is after leak function is finished and returned, "ch" will be out of scope and should be garbage collected, but its open and go-routine waits indefinitely for value to receive from it,
what is actually ahappening??

Comment: Your understanding of how GC works in Go is just plain wrong. Stuff is eligible for collection if unreachable from any live object. Scope doesn’t matter at all.

Comment: You cannot test if something is “out of scope" in your code, because by definition if you can reference it in your code it is reachable in some scope. (You also mention the closing of the channel, which is not a cleanup operation but a specific channel message)

Answer (score 2):

After the `leak()` func returns, there's still a goroutine with a reference to the channel - the one you created inside of `leak()` . That goroutine is still running, and it is blocked on the receive from the channel. Because there's a reference, it can't be garbage collected.

To be clear, garbage collection is not about "it's out of scope", but rather "there are no references to it". In this case, there's still a reference to the channel (in the spawned goroutine)